# HTML5: whiteboard dimension?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm creating a simple whiteboard using html5 canvas.

I need to give the canvas a width and height. This causes the whiteboard to not work properly.

If I remove the width and height from the canvas, it works fine!

This is my code:

```js
 var myCanvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
 var ctx = myCanvas.getContext("2d");
    
    // Fill Window Width and Height
    myCanvas.width = window.innerWidth;
 myCanvas.height = window.innerHeight;
 
 // Set Background Color
    ctx.fillStyle="#fff";
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,myCanvas.width,myCanvas.height);
 
    // Mouse Event Handlers
 if(myCanvas){
  var isDown = false;
  var canvasX, canvasY;
  ctx.lineWidth = 5;
  
  $(myCanvas)
  .mousedown(function(e){
   isDown = true;
   ctx.beginPath();
   canvasX = e.pageX - myCanvas.offsetLeft;
   canvasY = e.pageY - myCanvas.offsetTop;
   ctx.moveTo(canvasX, canvasY);
  })
  .mousemove(function(e){
   if(isDown !== false) {
    canvasX = e.pageX - myCanvas.offsetLeft;
    canvasY = e.pageY - myCanvas.offsetTop;
    ctx.lineTo(canvasX, canvasY);
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#000";
    ctx.stroke();
   }
  })
  .mouseup(function(e){
   isDown = false;
   ctx.closePath();
  });
 }
 
 // Touch Events Handlers
 draw = {
  started: false,
  start: function(evt) {

   ctx.beginPath();
   ctx.moveTo(
    evt.touches[0].pageX,
    evt.touches[0].pageY
   );

   this.started = true;

  },
  move: function(evt) {

   if (this.started) {
    ctx.lineTo(
     evt.touches[0].pageX,
     evt.touches[0].pageY
    );

    ctx.strokeStyle = "#000";
    ctx.lineWidth = 5;
    ctx.stroke();
   }

  },
  end: function(evt) {
   this.started = false;
  }
 };
 
 // Touch Events
 myCanvas.addEventListener('touchstart', draw.start, false);
 myCanvas.addEventListener('touchend', draw.end, false);
 myCanvas.addEventListener('touchmove', draw.move, false);
 
 // Disable Page Move
 document.body.addEventListener('touchmove',function(evt){
  evt.preventDefault();
 },false);
```

```css
#myCanvas{

width:90%;
height:200px;
border:solid 1px #c8def0;
border-radius:10px;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myCanvas">
  Sorry, your browser does not support HTML5 canvas technology.
 </canvas>
```

basically, when I run the above code, the mouse doesn't go all the way down the canvas but if I remove the `canvas width and height`, it works fine.

Could someone please advice on this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use this: `ctx.width = myCanvas.width = window.innerWidth * 0.9;
ctx.height = myCanvas.height = window.innerHeight * 0.9;` and go from there (changing the element's size will not also change the context's size)

Comment: @ChrisG, where am I suppose to use that? I placed it after the: var ctx = myCanvas.getContext("2d"); but it does nothing.

Comment: It's supposed to replace/extend your existing lines, and it works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/2t4coyfy/

Comment: @ChrisG, its not really! You seem to removed the width and height in your example as well which is the whole point of my question!

Comment: To use the CSS values, you need this: `ctx.width = myCanvas.width = myCanvas.clientWidth;
ctx.height = myCanvas.height = myCanvas.clientHeight;`: https://jsfiddle.net/2t4coyfy/1/